# Can I use "we are renovating our house."?

Tags: passive-voice

I found a sentence "My parents are having our house renovated.".
Can I say also "My parents are renovating our house."?

Of course the house are renovated by carpenters, but someone who order it are the parents, isn't it?

Comment: I'd lean toward 'I'm getting our house renovated'. For the reason you mentioned! ;) However, I don't say the other one is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly acceptable usage. Unless you want to distance yourself from the renovation, I might actually go with "*We're* renovating our house" (which turns it into a family decision as opposed to something just your parents wanted), but either way, your family/your parents are presumably closely involved with the renovation process; you're hiring people to do the actual construction work, but you're ultimately in charge.

Comment: I used to work in renovating houses. I always found it rather pretentious for homeowners to say "we're remodeling our house", when they were only paying others to do it. That phrasing, seemed to belittle the efforts of those doing the actual work. Yes, it's a common way to say it, but it smacks of elitism.